# How can I utilize JAX library to speed up my code?

Tags: numpy, jit, jax

I have written a code that gets some vertex and rearranged them based on some rules. When the input contains big data, the code runs very slowly e.g. for 60000 loops it will take about 15 hours on google colab TPU runtime. I have found JAX is one of the best libraries to do so and trying to use it, but due to lack of experience in dealing with such big data and its related methods such as parallelization, I have faced to some problems. The following small sample is created to show what does the code doing:

```python
import numpy as np

# <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'> <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'> (m, 4) <class 'numpy.int64'>
nodes = np.ma.masked_array(np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 5, 1], [6, 4, 7, 5], [8, 6, 9, 7]],
                                    dtype=np.int64), mask=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

# <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (n, 3) <class 'numpy.float64'>
vert = np.array([[0.06944111, -0.12027553, -0.3], [0., -0.13888221, -0.3], [0.05, -0.08660254, -0.3],
                [0.06944111, -0.12027553, -0.5], [0.06944111, -0.12027553, -0.1], [0., -0.13888221, -0.1],
                [0.06944111, -0.12027553,  0.1], [0., -0.13888221,  0.1], [0.06944111, -0.12027553,  0.3],
                [0., -0.13888221,  0.3]])


def ali_sh():
    mod_array = []
    mod_idx = []

    for cell in range(len(nodes)):
        vertex_idx = []

        B_face = sorted(nodes[cell], key=lambda v: [vert[v][0]], reverse=True)
        if round(vert[B_face[1]][0], 7) == round(vert[B_face[2]][0], 7):
            if vert[B_face[1]][1] > vert[B_face[2]][1]:
                B_face[1], B_face[2] = B_face[2], B_face[1]

        mod_array.append(B_face)

        for vertex in B_face:
            vertex_idx.append(np.where(nodes[cell] == vertex)[0][0])

        mod_idx.append(vertex_idx)

    return mod_idx

mod_idx = ali_sh()
```

The above code is just a view of my code and have some differences e.g. in this code `jnp.where` run correctly but using [the main code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ifTrA4WbtMLe8eZD5OHyRtfOE5ABK9V_?usp=sharing) and [the big data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lqvigrxd_FR5jgTdKbXku_pPsRLVEpl-/view?usp=sharing) it will stuck and must use `np.where` instead. In my first try, I have added `jax_r = jit(ali_sh)` and `mod_idx = jax_r().block_until_ready()` to the end of the code, but I did not get any better performance. I have used FiPy library and its methods, which where in numpy types e.g. 'fipy.mesh.vertexCoords.T' is a numpy ndarray. I have tried to convert the used fipy numpy arrays to JAX ones by `jnp.array(fipy numpy arrays)` to check if it could help, but I get errors due to using `lambda` by `sorted` command. How can I implement JAX on my code to get a better run time.

Does **colab** need anything to do to get its maximum capability on TPU or GPU for such codes?
Does using JAX could have significant effects on my code to speeding up? I would be appreciated if someone could help to find out how to speed up the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing efficient JAX code is very similar to writing efficient NumPy code: generally if you are using a `for` loop over rows of your data, your code will not be very efficient. Instead, you should strive to write your computations in terms of vectorized operations.

In your code, it looks like you are relying on many non-JAX elements (e.g. NumPy masked arrays, operations in FiPy, etc.) so it's unlikely that JAX will be able to improve your runtime. I'd focus instead on rewriting your code to make efficient use of NumPy, replacing the `for`-loop logic with NumPy vectorized operations.

Here is an example of expressing your function in terms of vectorized operations:

```python
def ali_sh_vectorized():
  i_sort = np.argsort(vert[nodes, 0], axis=1)[:, ::-1]
  B_face = nodes[np.arange(nodes.shape[0])[:, None], i_sort]
  close = np.isclose(vert[B_face[:, 1],1], vert[B_face[:, 2], 2])
  larger = np.greater(vert[B_face[:, 1],1], vert[B_face[:, 2], 2])
  col_1 = np.where(close & larger, B_face[:, 2], B_face[:, 1])
  col_2 = np.where(close & larger, B_face[:, 1], B_face[:, 2])
  B_face[:, 1] = col_1
  B_face[:, 2] = col_2
  mod_idx = np.where(nodes[:, :, None] == B_face[:, None, :])[2].reshape(nodes.shape)
  return mod_idx
```

The differences in the output compared to the original function are due to differences in how the Python sort and the NumPy sort handle equivalent elements, but I believe the overall logic is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful notes. Your written code will have at least twice the speed compared to my code. I must check its accuracy and differences in outputs by various input data.  Based on my previous tries by `np.isclose` in this code, this method may fail to get my desired results. Because this reason, I did not use this in the code. I must try to use numpy as you said, using your written code style, and check the results again.  
Can I use JAX now to accelerate further, If I convert masked arrays and ... to jnp ones? How?

Comment: Yes, if you have vectorized code and the inputs are `jax.numpy` arrays, wrapping the function in `jit` should yield speedups. Note that JAX has no masked array type, so if your logic depends on `nodes` being a masked array, you'll have to modify the logic before converting it to JAX.

Comment: I wrote a [code to compare JAX run speed with NumPy](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14af7zBKOFkk55AscAb7PcfGlU1Jf9c4k?usp=sharing); JAX runs the code about 50 times faster in one case where I put `@jit` before the function. I have problem with speeding up the run time using ` jax_r = jit(jax_) ` and ` jax_r() `, It, even, down the speed about 85% than NumPy. I couldn’t find out why error ` AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'block_until_ready' ` was appeared when I have tried to use ` jax_r().block_until_ready()`? What is the fastest method in JAX to run my code?

Comment: That error indicates that you're calling `.block_until_ready()` on the return value of a function with no return statement. Try returning the value you're computing from the function.